# alternative error message for asp.net error

Tags: asp.net, razor

I get the error when entering script tag

```
    A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected
 from the client (memberRequest="<script>alert("hi...").
```

I would like to give informational error message to user instead of this how to do ?

Answer (score 3):

You should use the Application_Error event inside your global.asax. Any unhandled exceptions are caught inside here and you can forward them to a custom error page.

More info can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3(v=vs.100).aspx

You could also use the Page_Error event. More info can be found here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306355